# What is the geometric interpretation of the Arithmetic–geometric mean?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

The [arithmetic–geometric mean](https://web.archive.org/web/20180502164900/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) of 2 values $a_0$,$b_0$, is the value to which the arithmetic and geometric values converge, being $$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}{2} \text{ and } b_n=\sqrt{a_{n-1} .b_{n-1}}$$
with
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = AGM(a_0,b_0)$$

The arithmetic and the geometric values have [a simple geometrical interpretation](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt669/student.folders/callinan.michael/Essays/Essay2/Essay2.html)

[image]

if $a_0$ is the segment FE, and $b_0$ is the segment EG, then the radius CD is the arithmetic mean, and the segment ED is the geometric mean.

**Is possible to draw the arithmetic–geometric mean on that circle (or there is another geometrical interpretation maybe not involving circles)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **angular average** of the distance between the perimeter of an ellipse and its centre:

\begin{align*}
  \langle r \rangle_{\theta} &=
  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r \, d\theta \\
  &= \frac{1}{2\pi}
  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{a b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 \theta+b^2\cos^2 \theta}} \, d\theta \\
  &= \frac{2ab}{\pi}
  \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2 \theta+b^2\cos^2 \theta}} \\
  &= \frac{ab}{\operatorname{agm}(a,b)}
\end{align*}

Comment: That's an useful answer, but would be more useful if were possible to construct the AGM geometrically. (Note 1: your a,b are not my $a_0, b_0$). (Note 2: In the circle, it reduces to $AGM(r,r)=\frac {r^2} {r}$)

Comment: @zugatevej: If it were possible to construct the AGM in a finite process, it would seem that it would not follow the limit-driven definition given in the OP.

Comment: @Brian Tung: a and b are known from the start. You are saying that <r> cannot be constructed. A limit does not guarantee that the limit value can not be constructed with finite steps. Also, the construction is not limited to compass and rule.

Comment: @zugatevej: That's not my intent. I mean to say that whatever construction there is would not follow the derivation given above.  It would not be *pedagogically* direct, even though it might be proven that it's correct.