# What motivates the arithmetic-geometric mean?

Tags: motivation

What motivates the arithmetic-geometric mean? What inspires it? I understand [how to calculate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2386984/30109) this mean but do not understand what might prompt a mathematician to pursue such a mean in the first place.

Is there a notion or mental image that conjures this thing?

(See also [this related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2168966/30109) If it helps you to pitch your answer at the right level, I am a [STEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science,_technology,_engineering,_and_mathematics) professional but not a professional mathematician.)

Comment: The [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com) might be a good place for this question.

Comment: @Blue Thank you. I have removed the historical reference to Gauss. After answerers have had some time to answer the revised question here, I might ask the historical question over there.

Comment: here it is given an application of agm: http://www.pgccphy.net/ref/arithgeom.pdf

Comment: You can potentially factor a number with related math.

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia article [Elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) states

> The complete elliptic integral of the first kind is sometimes called the quarter period. It can be computed very efficiently in terms of the arithmetic–geometric mean:
> $$ K(k)=\frac{\frac\pi2}{\text{agm}(1,\sqrt{1-k^2})}. $$

Thus, the motivation is to compute complete elliptic integrals. The Wikipedia article [Arithmetic-geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) states

> The first algorithm based on this sequence pair appeared in the works of Lagrange. Its properties were further analyzed by Gauss.

It was used extensively by Adrien-Marie Legendre in
computing his tables of elliptic integrals contained
in *Traité des Fonctions Elliptiques*, published in
three volumes 1825, 1826, and 1830.

So much for historical facts. Your question was

> Is there a notion or mental image that conjures this thing?

These are very rarely recorded. The facts indicate that
there was a need to compute complete elliptic integrals,
and somehow one or more mathematicians were able to develop
an equation which related elliptic integrals with different
parameters. The first instance seems to be due to John Landen.
The [DLMF section 19.8(ii) Landen transformations](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.8.ii) has the following equations

> Let $$ k_1 = \frac{1-k'}{1+k'}, $$
> Then
> $$K(k) = (1+k_1)K(k_1), \\
>  \qquad\quad\;\;\, E(k) = (1+k')E(k_1)-k'K(k).$$

You can refer to the Wikipedia article [Landen's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landen%27s_transformation) for
more details.

Comment: You can nearly factor a composite with it.