# Ellipse mean radius: most accurate estimation

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, means

What would be the most accurate estimation of the mean/average radius of an elliptic distribution with radii: semi-major axis `rmax` and semi-minor axis `rmin` among these? Are there others?

1. `r_mean = sqrt((rmax^2 + rmin^2)/2)`
2. `r_mean = (2*rmax + rmin)/3`
3. `r_mean = sqrt(rmax + rmin)`

The distribution arises from two independent variables U and V: when represented in 2D space they yield an elliptic shape.

Comment: Perhaps include a reference for "elliptic distribution".

Comment: Equating the area of an ellipse to that of a circle of radius equivalent to the average radius gives you the geometric mean of the semi minor and major axes

Comment: "Most accurate" with respect to what?

Comment: Please refer to my answers for other posts at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593146/why-mathematically-does-a-closed-curve-parametrized-by-theta-give-the-corre/2593173#2593173) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168966/what-is-the-geometric-interpretation-of-the-arithmetic-geometric-mean/2169020#2169020).

Comment: @Tak: many thanks. I am more inclined accept the angular average method, given sounder mathematical rationale/robustness. I tested it against 1 and 3 and all three are consistent. Can you please post it to close this question.